# Got TLS error: FATAL alert returned by server: HANDSHAKE_FAILURE

Tags: python, ssl, scapy

I am getting error `Got TLS error: FATAL alert returned by server: HANDSHAKE_FAILURE` while handshaking in the below code. what may be the issue ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import with_statement
from __future__ import print_function
try:
    # This import works from the project directory
    from scapy_ssl_tls.ssl_tls import *
except ImportError:
    # If you installed this package via pip, you just need to execute this
    from scapy.layers.ssl_tls import *

tls_version = TLSVersion.TLS_1_2
ciphers = [TLSCipherSuite.ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
# ciphers = [TLSCipherSuite.ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384]
# ciphers = [TLSCipherSuite.RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
# ciphers = [TLSCipherSuite.RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA]
# ciphers = [TLSCipherSuite.DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
# ciphers = [TLSCipherSuite.DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
extensions = [TLSExtension() / TLSExtECPointsFormat(),
              TLSExtension() / TLSExtSupportedGroups()]


def tls_client(ip):
    with TLSSocket(client=True) as tls_socket:
        try:
            print("kooo")
            tls_socket.connect(ip)
            print("Connected to server: %s" % (ip,))
        except socket.timeout:
            print("Failed to open connection to server: %s" % (ip,), file=sys.stderr)
        else:
            try:
                server_hello, server_kex = tls_socket.do_handshake(tls_version, ciphers, extensions)
                server_hello.show()
                tls_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_TTL, 20)
            except TLSProtocolError as tpe:
                print("Got TLS error: %s" % tpe, file=sys.stderr)
                tpe.response.show()
            else:
                resp = tls_socket.do_round_trip(TLSPlaintext(data="GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: pirate.trade\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.78 Safari/537.36\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6\r\n"))
                print("Got response from server")
                resp.show()
            # finally:
            #     print(tls_socket.tls_ctx)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) > 2:
        server = (sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]))
    else:
        server = ("pirate.trade", 443)
tls_client(server)
```

The above code is taken this link.  [https://github.com/tintinweb/scapy-ssl_tls/blob/master/examplesfull_rsa_connection_with_application_data.py](https://github.com/tintinweb/scapy-ssl_tls/blob/master/examples/full_rsa_connection_with_application_data.py)

Comment: My guess is that this is related to a missing SNI extension since the server pirate.trade requires it.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Can you please tell, how can I add SNI extension here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with running the shown code against `pirate.trade`.

The first one is that the site supports only ECDSA ciphers since it has only a ECDSA certificate. This can be seen for example from looking at [the SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=pirate.trade&s=2400%3acb00%3a2048%3a1%3a0%3a0%3a681f%3a1103&latest) when looking at the reported ciphers or certificate. To fix replace this line offering only an RSA cipher

```
ciphers = [TLSCipherSuite.ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
```

with this line offering an ECDSA cipher

```
ciphers = [TLSCipherSuite.ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
```

The second problem is that the site requires the SNI TLS extension. This can also be seen from the SSLLabs report:

> This site works only in browsers with SNI support.

This extension can be added by modifying the already existing extensions:

```
extensions = [TLSExtension() / TLSExtECPointsFormat(),
              TLSExtension() / TLSExtSupportedGroups(),
              TLSExtension() / TLSExtServerNameIndication(server_names=TLSServerName(data="pirate.trade"))]
```

Only if both fixes are done the handshake succeeds.